# Wget cannot validate https://ftp.gnu.org?

Tags: solaris, wget, ssl, certificates, download

I'm working on Solaris and trying to upgrade Git by building Git and all of its dependencies from sources. Wget is failing to download a dependency, which is located at `https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libunistring/libunistring-0.9.7.tar.gz`.

```
$ wget --ca-certificate="$HOME/.cacert/lets-encrypt-root-x3.pem" "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libunistring/libunistring-0.9.7.tar.gz" -O libunistring-0.9.7.tar.gz
--2017-10-14 17:59:40--  https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libunistring/libunistring-0.9.7.tar.gz
Resolving ftp.gnu.org (ftp.gnu.org)... 208.118.235.20, 2001:4830:134:3::b
Connecting to ftp.gnu.org (ftp.gnu.org)|208.118.235.20|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify ftp.gnu.org's certificate, issued by 'CN=Let\'s Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let\'s Encrypt,C=US':
  unable to get issuer certificate
To connect to ftp.gnu.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Below is the chain as seen by OpenSSL, and it verifies the subject and issuers. It is also the same certificate listed at [Let's Encrypt Chain of Trust | Let’s Encrypt Authority X3 (IdenTrust cross-signed)](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/).

I can duplicate the problem on Linux with Fedora 26. And the equivalent cURL command works as expected.

How do I tell Wget to use `CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3` as the trust point for the download?

---

This version of Wget was already upgraded by building from sources.

```
$ wget -V
GNU Wget 1.19.1 built on solaris2.11.

-cares +digest -gpgme +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file -metalink +nls
+ntlm +opie -psl +ssl/openssl

Wgetrc:
    /usr/local/etc/wgetrc (system)
Locale:
    /usr/local/share/locale
Compile:
    gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/usr/local/etc/wgetrc"
    -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/local/share/locale" -I. -I../lib -I../lib
    -I/usr/local/include -DNDEBUG -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/pcre
    -DNDEBUG -m64
Link:
    gcc -I/usr/include/pcre -DNDEBUG -m64 -m64
    -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib64 -lpcre -luuid -lidn2
    /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so
    -R/usr/local/lib64 -ldl -lz -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lpthread
    ftp-opie.o openssl.o http-ntlm.o ../lib/libgnu.a -lsocket -lnsl
    -lnsl -lnsl -lsocket -lsocket /usr/local/lib64/libiconv.so
    -R/usr/local/lib64 /usr/local/lib64/libunistring.so
    /usr/local/lib64/libiconv.so -ldl -lpthread -R/usr/local/lib64
    -lsocket
...
```

---

The equivalent cURL command works as expected. The problem is, Wget is always available, but cURL may need to be installed. I don't want to depend on a program that may (or may not) be installed.

```
$ curl --cacert "$HOME/.cacert/lets-encrypt-root-x3.pem" "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libunistring/libunistring-0.9.7.tar.gz" -o libunistring-0.9.7.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 3505k  100 3505k    0     0  3505k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 3249k
```

---

```
$ openssl x509 -in ~/.cacert/lets-encrypt-root-x3.pem -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            0a:01:41:42:00:00:01:53:85:73:6a:0b:85:ec:a7:08
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: O=Digital Signature Trust Co., CN=DST Root CA X3
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 17 16:40:46 2016 GMT
            Not After : Mar 17 16:40:46 2021 GMT
        Subject: C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:9c:d3:0c:f0:5a:e5:2e:47:b7:72:5d:37:83:b3:
                    68:63:30:ea:d7:35:26:19:25:e1:bd:be:35:f1:70:
                    92:2f:b7:b8:4b:41:05:ab:a9:9e:35:08:58:ec:b1:
                    2a:c4:68:87:0b:a3:e3:75:e4:e6:f3:a7:62:71:ba:
                    79:81:60:1f:d7:91:9a:9f:f3:d0:78:67:71:c8:69:
                    0e:95:91:cf:fe:e6:99:e9:60:3c:48:cc:7e:ca:4d:
                    77:12:24:9d:47:1b:5a:eb:b9:ec:1e:37:00:1c:9c:
                    ac:7b:a7:05:ea:ce:4a:eb:bd:41:e5:36:98:b9:cb:
                    fd:6d:3c:96:68:df:23:2a:42:90:0c:86:74:67:c8:
                    7f:a5:9a:b8:52:61:14:13:3f:65:e9:82:87:cb:db:
                    fa:0e:56:f6:86:89:f3:85:3f:97:86:af:b0:dc:1a:
                    ef:6b:0d:95:16:7d:c4:2b:a0:65:b2:99:04:36:75:
                    80:6b:ac:4a:f3:1b:90:49:78:2f:a2:96:4f:2a:20:
                    25:29:04:c6:74:c0:d0:31:cd:8f:31:38:95:16:ba:
                    a8:33:b8:43:f1:b1:1f:c3:30:7f:a2:79:31:13:3d:
                    2d:36:f8:e3:fc:f2:33:6a:b9:39:31:c5:af:c4:8d:
                    0d:1d:64:16:33:aa:fa:84:29:b6:d4:0b:c0:d8:7d:
                    c3:93
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            Authority Information Access:
                OCSP - URI:http://isrg.trustid.ocsp.identrust.com
                CA Issuers - URI:http://apps.identrust.com/roots/dstrootcax3.p7c

            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:C4:A7:B1:A4:7B:2C:71:FA:DB:E1:4B:90:75:FF:C4:15:60:85:89:10

            X509v3 Certificate Policies:
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.44947.1.1.1
                  CPS: http://cps.root-x1.letsencrypt.org

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.identrust.com/DSTROOTCAX3CRL.crl

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                A8:4A:6A:63:04:7D:DD:BA:E6:D1:39:B7:A6:45:65:EF:F3:A8:EC:A1
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         dd:33:d7:11:f3:63:58:38:dd:18:15:fb:09:55:be:76:56:b9:
         70:48:a5:69:47:27:7b:c2:24:08:92:f1:5a:1f:4a:12:29:37:
         24:74:51:1c:62:68:b8:cd:95:70:67:e5:f7:a4:bc:4e:28:51:
         cd:9b:e8:ae:87:9d:ea:d8:ba:5a:a1:01:9a:dc:f0:dd:6a:1d:
         6a:d8:3e:57:23:9e:a6:1e:04:62:9a:ff:d7:05:ca:b7:1f:3f:
         c0:0a:48:bc:94:b0:b6:65:62:e0:c1:54:e5:a3:2a:ad:20:c4:
         e9:e6:bb:dc:c8:f6:b5:c3:32:a3:98:cc:77:a8:e6:79:65:07:
         2b:cb:28:fe:3a:16:52:81:ce:52:0c:2e:5f:83:e8:d5:06:33:
         fb:77:6c:ce:40:ea:32:9e:1f:92:5c:41:c1:74:6c:5b:5d:0a:
         5f:33:cc:4d:9f:ac:38:f0:2f:7b:2c:62:9d:d9:a3:91:6f:25:
         1b:2f:90:b1:19:46:3d:f6:7e:1b:a6:7a:87:b9:a3:7a:6d:18:
         fa:25:a5:91:87:15:e0:f2:16:2f:58:b0:06:2f:2c:68:26:c6:
         4b:98:cd:da:9f:0c:f9:7f:90:ed:43:4a:12:44:4e:6f:73:7a:
         28:ea:a4:aa:6e:7b:4c:7d:87:dd:e0:c9:02:44:a7:87:af:c3:
         34:5b:b4:42
```

---

```
$ openssl s_client -connect ftp.gnu.org:443 -servername ftp.gnu.org -showcerts
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=ftp.gnu.org
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/CN=ftp.gnu.org
issuer=/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3

...
```

Comment: Now open on the Bug-Wget mailing list: [Wget cannot validate https://ftp.gnu.org?](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2017-10/msg00004.html) I'm fairly certain its a Wget bug because things should work, and cURL works as expected.

Comment: Why is it a wget bug if openssl also presents a verification error? `"verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate "`

Comment: @bishop - By default, OpenSSL has an empty CA list, so its expected to fail. That is, OpenSSL trusts nothing by default. I could fix it by adding `-CAfile` to `openssl s_client`. But in the case of the `wget` command, it has the CA specified. (I can add `-CAfile` if it helps the reading, but its just an academic exercise).

Comment: Right. Can you also post the working openssl command and output, please?

Comment: Does look buggy. What version of libssl here, and the Fedora box?

Comment: @bishop - Arg... [Why did RFC 4158 (Path Building) restrict Trust Anchors to self-signed certificates?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/171296/29925) OpenSSL versions on all machines are the latest, which is OpenSSL 1.0.2l at the time of this writing.

Comment: The (first) cert you show in `~/.cacert/lets-encrypt-root-x3.pem` is the intermediate cert not the root. Does it _also_ contain the root cert for DST Root CA X3? The fact curl likes it suggests so _if_ this build of curl uses OpenSSL which not all do, and doesn't separate the trustfiles-vs-dir. OpenSSL will not validate a chain that doesn't end at a root unless it's at least 1.0.2 and for commandline you specify `-partial_chain` or for a program it does the equivalent (non-default) option -- and it will fail with the verifyerr you show, unable to get issuer.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 -  The *Let's Encrypt X3* is where I am attempting to anchor trust. It happens to be cross-certified so end-entity certificates "just work" in browsers that lack Let's Encrypt X3 root. Thanks for `-partial_chain`; it works around the issue in OpenSSL. I was searching for the words "anchor" and "trust" in `s_client` man page, so I missed "partial" and "chain". Let me try and find a similar switch in Wget.

Comment: (ninja) BTW 4158 is stated to apply to 3280, which is superseded by 5280 which is fairly vague about anchor certs (as a realization of more abstract anchors). Also FYI OpenSSL _commandline (not library) does_ have a default truststore but until recently (except on RedHat) s_client,s_server,s_time (but not other commands) had a bug that caused the default to not work. And what's _in_ the default truststore may vary by platform/options/environment.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate you stored in `~/.cacert/lets-encrypt-root-x3.pem` should not be left alone since it is an intermediate certificate. As you may see, it is issued by `O=Digital Signature Trust Co., CN=DST Root CA X3`. When passing to wget the ca-certificate argument, the specified file should a list of all CA certificates in PEM format. And this list is used insted of the default one.

So, if you download the `O=Digital Signature Trust Co., CN=DST Root CA X3` certificate in PEM format, you attach it at the end of your `~/.cacert/lets-encrypt-root-x3.pem`, then wget should not complain.

Answer (score 0):

As of xenial (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS) the 1.17.1-1ubuntu1.3 version of wget interoperates with that FTP site just fine, out of the box.

Comment: The problem seems to be with building `wget` against OpenSSL. The distro version does not use OpenSSL. I think it uses Gcrypt or GnuPG for the crypto instead (which means OpenSSL and its verification code is not used). Also see [Wget cannot validate https://ftp.gnu.org?](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2017-10/msg00004.html)

Answer (score -1):

Try to install a `wget` from **opencsw** this is where you get a maintained openssl library to link wget against.

Since wget works to this URL if you are on Linux, the problem must be cause by an outdated OpenSSL.